# float between 0.0 and 15.0 to uint8_t

Tags: floating-point, integer, precision

I am writing code that at some point needs to convert from a `float` to a `uint8_t`. The cool part is, the float already has the same value as the `uint8_t`, e.g. `15.0` => `15`, or `4.0` => `4`.

I need to now write a function that converts the `32-bit float` to a `32-bit unsigned integer`, such that the value of the float and the integer are the same. Hence, only the first `4 bits` of the integer could ever be set.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
Binary representation for: 0.0  00000000000000000000000000000000 => 0000

Binary representation for: 1.0  00011111110000000000000000000000 => 0001

Binary representation for: 2.0  00100000000000000000000000000000 => 0010

Binary representation for: 3.0  00100000001000000000000000000000 => 0011

Binary representation for: 4.0  00100000010000000000000000000000 => 0100

Binary representation for: 5.0  00100000010100000000000000000000 => 0101

Binary representation for: 6.0  00100000011000000000000000000000 => 0110

Binary representation for: 7.0  00100000011100000000000000000000 => 0111

Binary representation for: 8.0  00100000100000000000000000000000 => ....

Binary representation for: 9.0  00100000100010000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 10.0 00100000100100000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 11.0 00100000100110000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 12.0 00100000101000000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 13.0 00100000101010000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 14.0 00100000101100000000000000000000

Binary representation for: 15.0 00100000101110000000000000000000
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Most languages have a builtin function to do so. Is there some reason you can't use that? Or is this purely theoretical?

Comment: Ah, Can you think of a cool way to manipulate the bits to have the integer representation on the 4 least significant bits? I know a lookup table would work, but is there a nice trick?

Comment: I am writing AVX intrinsics to write performant code, so casting to uint8_t is not going to give me any speedup, because I have to write scalar code in my particular case.

Comment: surely just casting the float to int does what you want. And you think thats too slow?

Comment: Casting is too slow. I'm writing performant code, so I need to figure out a faster way of doing it. Plus, these floats are in AVX registers, so I need to manipulate all 8 at the same time so that only the 4 least-significant bits are set.

Comment: What's wrong with just `_mm256_cvtps_epi32`?